# Running a Postgresql Query at a specific time

Tags: postgresql, datetime, triggers, cron

**Scenario**

I have a table which contains tasks that need to be completed by a specific datetime. If the task is not completed by this datetime (+- variable interval) then it will run a script to 'escalate' this task. 
This variable interval can be as small as 2 seconds or as large as 2 years

**Thoughts so far**

Running a cron job every second either via pg_cron or similar will technically allow me to do a check on the database every second, however there is a lot of wasted processing here and a lot of database overhead and i'd rather not do this if possible.

Triggers can be fired on row insert/update/delete. so worst case scenario is we have an external script watching for these triggers being fired.

**Question**

Is there a way to schedule a query to run at a specific time, ideally within postgresql itself rather than via a bash/cron script. ie:

```
at 2017-09-30 09:32:00 - select * from table where datetime <= now
```

**Edit**

As it came up in the comments PGAgent is a possibility and the scenario for such would be:

The task is created by the user in the application, and the due date is set (eg 2017-09-28 13:00:00) the user has an interval before/after this due date where the task is escalated (eg One Hour Before) so at 12:00:00 on 2017-09-28 i want PGAgent/other option to run my sql script that does the escalation.

The script to escalate is already written and works, the date and time for this PGAgent script to be run is already calculated by another script.

Comment: Sounds like PgAgent will do what you want. https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/pgagent.html

Comment: PgAgent is definitely one route that i have and will further look into, although from what i've seen so far it appears to require some form of GUI to create the script? or do i need a new set of glasses?  Ideally this script will be generated from within my application (back-end/server-side)

Comment: You have to install it, then there is a GUI to create the job, steps and schedule - I'm sure you could job creation in SQL, but I never tried. I had a set up where a job ran every minute; the job ran one SQL query to call a stored procedure with the actual logic. That might be an efficient way for you - if the first line of the procedure is your logical check you should have low overheads.

Comment: The main issue with a GUI is this is going to be run on a 'headless' linux server. As well as this the code needs to be generated at 'run time'. So basically when a user creates a task with a 'due date', on that due date (+- interval, which is related to that task) the script is run.

Comment: The "GUI" to configure PGAgent sits in PGAdmin, which can run on any client machine - i.e. separate from the server. For me, the point of a schedule is that it runs at a predetermined time/frequency - set it up once, then forget it. If you have variable stuff, I'd write that into a table and have the scheduled task run a procedure that checks if there are any records in the table that it has to to process.

Comment: I just realised i  was probably not clear in my description in the last comment.
The task is created by the user in the application, and the due date is set (2017-09-28 13:00:00). the user has an interval before/after this due date where the task is escalated (-1hr) so at 12:00:00 on 2017-09-28 i want PGAgent/other option to run my sql script that does the escalation.
As this due date and time and the interval are input by the user via the application. If i were to use PGAgent then the script to run the escalation once at the date and time selected would need to be created 'on the fly'.